# Delete row + the following 2 rows if a certain row name using UNIX

Tags: awk, grep

I'm using UNIX, and wondered if I can use grep or awk or something else for the following:

If you have a file:

```
Delete-me  
1  
2  
3  
4  
Delete-me  
1  
2  
3  
4  
Delete-me  
1  
2  
3  
4
```

How can I get this output:

```
3  
4  
3  
4  
3  
4
```

Comment: What's the logic ? What language ?

Comment: And in what language?

Comment: Hi! Sorry, Im using UNIX (osx). A simple bash line would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '/Delete-me/ {getline;getline;getline;print;getline;print}'
3
4
3
4
3
4
```

---

Another way

```
awk 'NR%5==0 || NR%5==4'
3
4
3
4
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/Delete-me/{c=3} c&&c--{next} 1' file
3
4
3
4
3
4
```

Comment: You're welcome. This is THE idiomatic awk way to do it. I see you selected the getline approach as your answer. That is completely the wrong way to do it. Imagine modifying both scripts if you had to skip 20 lines instead of 3 and print some variable number of lines after that. With the non-getline approach you change 3 to 20. Now imagine you want to print "found" for every line that contains the word "foo". With the non-getline approach you add one `/foo/{print "found"}`. Read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and make sure you understand the many caveats before you ever consider using getline.